# Prestashop 1.7 default theme. Where is the list view?

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In prestashop 1.6, we have two different ways to show products in "list view" and "grid view"
However in the default theme of the newest version of Prestashop 1.7, we have only one option as "grid view".

Has Prestashop removed the list view or must be enabled from back office?

Comment: Hi Josias, I found this for you: https://mypresta.eu/prestashop-17/grid-list-switcher-in-category-view.html . I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Aurora. yes, it's usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality to display products in "list view" instead of grid view in Prestashop 1.7.